# Sending gifts to Italy

Tags: gifts

What is the maximum allowable value of gifts sent to Italy to avoid customs duties?   Does the receiving party have to pay VAT on items?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: I assume you mean send by post? If so, this is not a travel question.